# org-mode internal link works only in some cases

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I have an `.org` document with the following structure.

```
* Headline 1
This is some text

* Headline 2
:Custom_id: h2

This is heading number two

** Sub heading 1
<<target>>

** Sub heading 2

* Headline 3
In conclusion, this is an example


1. [[Headline 1]]
2. [[#h2]]
3. [[target]]
```

Only `[[h2]]` with the custom id works for me. The others just bring me to the top of the document. When I change `[[target]]` to some other string such as `[[孔子]]` though, it will work.

What went wrong?

Comment: The link is working for me like expected with Emacs 26.1 (running as `emacs -Q`) and built in Orgmode 9.1.9 as well as with Orgmode 9.1.13. Point moves to the third first-level section.

Comment: Mine is also Emacs 26.1 with orgmode 9.19. How do I find out what's wrong?

Comment: First step is to try `emacs -Q`. If that works the problem lies within your init files. You can start `emacs -Q` from within emacs by `M-& emacs -Q <RET>`.

Comment: emacs: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs.
It lacks the ability to position the cursor.
If that is not the actual type of terminal you have,
use the Bourne shell command `TERM=... export TERM' (C-shell:
`setenv TERM ...') to specify the correct type.  It may be necessary
to do `unset TERMINFO' (C-shell: `unsetenv TERMINFO') as well.

Comment: You are running Emacs on a terminal frame? Maybe, it is an encoding problem. Please, try with a heading only containing ascii characters.

Comment: It's a mac desktop version

Comment: @Tobias in my new sample above, running on `emacs -Q` fixes `1` and `3` but spoils `2`. Error msg: `No match for custom ID: h2`

Comment: Put `:Custom_id: h2` into a [property drawer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html).